# ForkAfterAuthentication and SessionType in .ssh/config Fail

Tags: ssh

I've entered the following options for a specific host in my `.ssh/config` file:

```
    ForkAfterAuthentication yes
    SessionType none
```

However, when trying to connect to the host, it fails with:

```
.ssh/config: line 7: Bad configuration option: forkafterauthentication
.ssh/config: line 8: Bad configuration option: sessiontype
.ssh/config: terminating, 2 bad configuration options
```

The same options work just fine when used directly on the command line.

Is there a specific version of OpenSSH that added those options in the `.ssh/config` file?  I tried it with `OpenSSH_7.2p2` and `OpenSSH_8.2p1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://www.openssh.com/releasenotes.html, both of those ssh_config options were introduced in version 8.7. (The pull request is https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/pull/231 .)